# am I rightly understand what means LTS for Java?

Tags: java, java-8, java-11, java-6, lts

am I rightly understand what means LTS for Java?
my understanding:

A lot of time after the release of the LTS version, if the support period has not yet expired, this version may receive an update despite the fact that even a new LTS version has already been released, for example, can JDK 17.0.7 get an update to 17.0.8 in 2023 when JDK 20 was released?

I just want to make sure of my understanding

Comment: LTS (long-term support) is a version that is to be supported for up to n-years after release. Java 8 has the longest support up to 2030 (16 years after its release). See: [Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html#:~:text=For%20product%20releases%20after%20Java,Java%2021%20in%20September%202023.) for all the support dates for all current (and upcoming) LTS releases. If you are using Java 8, try to upgrade to 11, before transitioning to 17 or 21.

Comment: Mr. Polywhirl, thank you, it is helpfull

Comment: In contrast, Oracle's current policy is to support non-LTS versions only until the next version is released.  And their current practice is to release a new version every six months.

Comment: Please do not write "JAVA". The name of the language is Java.